Server-side sorting in data table with infinite scroll
I have a question about the infinite scroll feature in DataTable (or DataGrid). After doing some research, I found that pagination might be more suitable for DataTable than infinite scroll. However, due to the nature of my app, I need to introduce infinite scroll.
Let's say that the infinite scroll feature in my app looks like:

In the initial state of my DataTable, I only show the first 50 rows of data.
When I scroll, it fetches another 50 rows of data.
In total, there are 5000(or more, whatever) rows of data.
We support server-side sorting.

And let's say the user scrolled and fetched about 1000 rows of data (i.e. 20 additional loads), and wants to sort by a specific column. Should the server return only the first 50 rows of the sorted data, or 1000 sorted rows (since they fetched 1000 rows before)?
If we return only the first 50 rows, the user will have to do 20 additional loads to see the 1000 rows again, is that the right way to go?

Server side sorting will always consider the entire 5000. But this does not change the fetching amount of 50. So it should still be passing batches of 50 records. It should not matter though because the whole point of sorting is to display correct results on the top. The user should not need to browse all the previous 1000 again.
Loading in batches will reduce load time for the user. Normally there is a timeout limit for backend processes. You can decide the upper limit of the batch size based on that. But loading time for the user is a completely separate topic.
Loading time of more than 5 seconds will increase bounce rate probability by more than 100 percent. So, the batch size should not demand loading time exceeding 5 seconds. You can preload the next 50 in the background if possible to reduce lazy load time.

A 1-3 seconds, web page load time increases bounce rate probability by 32%.
A 1-5 seconds, web page load time increases bounce rate probability by 90%.
A 1-6 seconds, web page load time increases the bounce rate probability by 106%.
A 1-10 seconds, web page load time increases the bounce rate probability by 123%.

Source: Key Website Load Time Statistics

Welcome to the site!
Why should the system load 1000 entries again?
I'd hope that sorting helps the user to find what they are looking for quickly, without looking at another 1000 entries. And why should the user be interested in the entries at position 950-1000 in a different sort order?
Sorting should always start over, showing the initial entries in the new sort order.

I really appreciate your answer.
